# Teams Bot responds slowly when using skills

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

When I use the sample code "81.skills-skilldialog"(https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples), the response time is a few seconds longer than the bot without skills. This may be the time when root calls skills. Is this normal or am I maybe doing something wrong?

The development environment uses C#, and the endpoints of Root bot and Skills are on local IIS Server.
In the same environment, the same bot is implemented using skills and non-skills respectively, and the response speed differs by about 2 to 5 seconds.

Comment: The slight delay when using skills in your bot, as compared to a bot without skills is because when a root bot calls a skill, it involves additional steps such as forwarding the activity to the skill, waiting for the skill to process the activity, and then sending the response back to the root bot. These additional steps can add to the overall response time.
However, a delay of 2 to 5 seconds seems a bit high. It could be due to various factors such as network latency, the complexity of the skill being called, or the performance of the local IIS server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How much time will this increase on average?